# get data from javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I have weird object:

```
{"Cats":10,"Dogs":815,"Fishes":2}
```

How can I get full value from each piece of data

```js
var t = {"Cats":10,"Dogs":815,"Fishes":2};
var keys = [];
for (var key in t) {
  if (t.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key)
  }
}
```

I'm getting only the names without number
I can use JSON.stringify and then manipulate that object but maybe there is other way?
Probably I missing something?

Comment: t[key] => yourObject[keyName]  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement iterate over the property names get the value by property name.

```js
var t = {"Cats":10,"Dogs":815,"Fishes":2};
var keys = [];
for (var key in t) {
  if (t.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key, t[key])
  }
}
```

---

If you would like to generate an array of values then use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods.

```js
var t = {  "Cats": 10,  "Dogs": 815,  "Fishes": 2};

var keys = Object.keys(t);
var values = keys.map(function(key) {
  return t[key];
});

console.log(keys, values);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var t = {"Cats":10,"Dogs":815,"Fishes":2};
var keys = [];
for (var key in t) {
  if (t.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key, t[key])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the own properties first with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and iterate then.

```js
var t = { Cats: 10, Dogs: 815, Fishes: 2 },
    keys = Object.keys(t);

keys.forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key, t[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = {"Cats":10,"Dogs":815,"Fishes":2};
for (var key in t)
{
  console.log(key, t[key]);
}
```